# How to see the actual commands blender runs

Tags: scripting

I'm writing some scripts for applying textures and got into troubles.

The commands showed in the info window seems to be only a part of the commands actually runs. I copied the demonstrated commands into a script to do the same things as what I do manually, but the script just fails. I guess it missed some commands setting the context.

So how can I see all the commands actually runs?

In addition, how to see the content of '...' like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Consult the docs**

What you are seeing in this instance is an object property. Blender uses operators as "command" clearly recognizable from `bpy.ops.` namespace.

For the case shown::

It has ID object of type screen (`bpy.types.Screen`) an instance `bpy.data.screens["Default"]` aka`context.screen`  and a property name of `texture_context`

This means we can find it from the screen object following chain of collections or pointers `screen.foo.bar[0].blah.texture_context` where none of `foo, bar, blah` will be an ID object. It is this chain that can be abbreviated to "...". Without can produce ridiculously wide tooltips.

(*Reminder to self*) Before pecking about aimlessly in the python console why not consult the docs.. Using the [right click and view docs outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126352/15543) will take you directly to the help page.

Searching the old** [API manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/search.html?q=texture_context&check_keywords=yes&area=default) using just the property name.

[image]

we find that [`texture_context`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceProperties.html?highlight=texture_context#bpy.types.SpaceProperties.texture_context) is a member of `bpy.types.SpaceProperties` as shown in tooltip.  A space belongs to an area, an area belongs to a screen.

You set the space of an area when selecting the editor type, in this case we want the area of type  `'PROPERTIES'`, aka the Properties editor which has an  active space of type `SpaceProperties`  (tip can toggle an using `area.type = 'PROPERTIES'`)

Scripting

Here is an example using the py console (`bpy.types.SpaceConsole`).

```
>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     if a.type == 'PROPERTIES':
...         i, a
...         break
...         
(1, bpy.data.screens['Scripting']...Area)
# bpy.data.screens['Scripting'].areas[1]    

>>> a.spaces.active.texture_context
'MATERIAL'

>>> space = a.spaces.active  
>>> space.texture_context = 'WORLD'
```

If your script is going to be invoked from a button or menu in the properties area, can use.

```
space = context.space_data
# or 
space = context.area.spaces.active
```

albeit this may seem convoluted, you'll find blender follows a pretty consistent data structure.

** Note

I believe this property has been removed from 2.80 and searching the [new manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/search.html?q=texture_context&check_keywords=yes&area=default) will direct you to the API changes page.

Answer (score 0):

run blender with the command line options of

```
--debug-wm
```

Which will give you a bit more output for the window manager and operator calls,

```
--debug-all
```

Which will dump just about everything

there are few more specific ones listed in the documentation

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

For the debug, just open the Blender console (Window > Toggle System Console): everything you do is reported there, and the print() function outputs there as well (so if you need to check the value of a variable 'var' in your script, just write print(var) and run the script).
For the second question, i don't have a full solution, but you can usually find the path you need by right clicking on the button/checkbox/fiels/etc... and then choosing "Online Python Reference" or "Edit Source". These will open up the Blender Manual or the actual code for that asset, which (again, usually) have the path you are looking for